# Jquery unable to get the response from WCF REST service

Tags: javascript, wcf, jquery, wcf-rest

I have developed WCF rest service and deployed it on a link that can be accessed via the browser because its action is "GET".

I want to get that data using jQuery. I tried my best to get WCf get response using jQuery
but in vain. I also tried $.Ajax with 'jsonp' with no luck. Can any one help me?

The url is: http://www.lonestarus.com/AndroidApp/AndroidLocation.svc/RestService/getLatestLocation

You can check that url response by pasting url in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to value [*] in your response header.

[this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/justinjsmith/archive/2007/08/22/setting-http-headers-in-wcf-net-3-5.aspx) gives the more details how it can be done in WCF REST service

if you were to do this in Web API you could have just added

```
 Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

calling the service using a fiddle

```
$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.lonestarus.com/AndroidApp/AndroidLocation.svc/RestService/getLatestLocation",
        datatype: 'json',
        type : 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            debugger;

            var obj = data;
        }

    });

})​;​
```

I got the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.lonestarus.com/AndroidApp/AndroidLocation.svc/RestService/getLatestLocation.
>   Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: where i need to add access control orign can you please tell me

Comment: by that way i added accesscontrol allow orign in w.cf's web.config.
now can you please try you code on i.E
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>

Comment: Getting Error : "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://www.lonestarus.com/AndroidApp/AndroidLocation.svc/RestService/getLatestLocation"

Comment: why we need to use jsonp there ? and can you please edit your answer  and paste jsfiddle code so that i can accept your answer right.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21844/discussion-between-frictionlesspulley-and-bilal-lilla)

Answer (score 1):

I can't make a cross domain example to show you but

```
$('#a').load('http://www.lonestarus.com/AndroidApp/AndroidLocation.svc/RestService/getLatestLocation​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​?callback=run');​
```

would work had those things been set.

Your service needs to either enable JSONP callbacks or set the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) header for cross domain requests to work, or you need to run the script from the same domain. Given that your url says AndroidApp I'm thinking you want cross domain.

Comment: note: setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`  will allow requests from any origin.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code below:

```
$.ajax
(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: http://www.lonestarus.com/AndroidApp/AndroidLocation.svc/RestService/getLatestLocation,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response, type, xhr)
        {
            window.alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr)
        {
            window.alert('error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I went ahead and changed it.  Although, I do need it to be true in my app, so it really depends on what you really need.

Comment: i just need to data inside the successfunction. and your code is not working giving error 'Error no transport'